# How do I solve "Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file." in an Android app?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, namespaces

So I have the main app module, `:app`

```
//**project build.gradle**
buildscript {
    extra["compose_version"] = "1.5.4"

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:1.9.21")
        classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.44")
        classpath("com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3")
        classpath("com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:2.0.0-Beta2")
    }
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.0"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "2.0.0-Beta2"
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44"
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.20-1.0.14"
}
```

```
**//:app module build.gradle**
...
android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.efest"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
}
...
```

```
**//:authentication module build.gradle**
...
android {
    namespace = "com.example.authentication"
    compileSdk = 34
}
...
```

```
**//:shared module build.gradle**
...
android {
    namespace = "com.example.shared"
    compileSdk = 34
}
...
```

And I get this error:

```
Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. 
See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for 
information about setting the namespace.

If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, 
you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the 
build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general 
information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.
```

And considering that I have specified the namespaces for each module, this error makes no sense whatsoever. So what am I missing or what is the solution to this?